# java converting .xls to csv

Tags: java, excel, csv, apache-poi

I have converted to .xls file to a csv file using the Apache POI library. I iterate each row and cell, put a comma, and append to the buffered reader. The cell types numeric and string are converted perfectly.  If a blank cell comes I put a comma, but blank values are not detected by the code. How to do it? Please help me out.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRichTextString;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFDateUtil;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil;
class convert {

static void convertToXls(File inputFile, File outputFile)
{
StringBuffer cellDData = new StringBuffer();
String cellDDataString=null;
try
{
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(inputFile));
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Cell cell=null;
        Row row;
        int previousCell;
        int currentCell;
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        while (rowIterator.hasNext())
        {
        previousCell = -1;
        currentCell = 0;
        row = rowIterator.next();
         System.out.println("ROW:-->");
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
        while (cellIterator.hasNext())
{
          // System.out.println("true" +cellIterator.hasNext());
        cell = cellIterator.next();
        currentCell = cell.getColumnIndex();


        System.out.println("CELL:-->" +cell.toString());
        try{
        switch (cell.getCellType())
        {

        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                cellDData.append(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + ",");
                System.out.println("boo"+ cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                break;

        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                         if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell))
                        {

                  //      System.out.println(cell.getDateCellValue());
                        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                            "dd/MM/yyyy");
                         String  strCellValue = dateFormat.format(cell.getDateCellValue());
                //      System.out.println("date:"+strCellValue);
                        cellDData.append(strCellValue +",");
                    }
                       else {
                        System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                        Double value = cell.getNumericCellValue();
                    Long longValue = value.longValue();
                    String strCellValue1 = new String(longValue.toString());
                //      System.out.println("number:"+strCellValue1);
                         cellDData.append(strCellValue1 +",");
                    }
        //      cellDData.append(cell.getNumericCellValue() + ",");
                //String  i=(new java.text.DecimalFormat("0").format( cell.getNumericCellValue()+"," ));
                //System.out.println("number"+cell.getNumericCellValue());
                break;

        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
   String out=cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString();
                cellDData.append(cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString() + ",");
                //System.out.println("string"+cell.getStringCellValue());
                break;

        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                cellDData.append("" + "THIS IS BLANK");
                System.out.print("THIS IS BLANK");
                break;

        default:
                break;
        }}
catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    //do something clever with the exception
                        System.out.println("nullException"+e.getMessage());
                }

}
        int len=cellDData.length() - 1;
//      System.out.println("length:"+len);
//      System.out.println("length1:"+cellDData.length());
       cellDData.replace(cellDData.length() - 1, cellDData.length() , "");
        cellDData.append("\n");
        }
        //cellDData.append("\n");


//String out=cellDData.toString();
//System.out.println("res"+out);

//String o = out.substring(0, out.lastIndexOf(","));
//System.out.println("final"+o);
fos.write(cellDData.toString().getBytes());
//fos.write(cellDDataString.getBytes());
fos.close();

}
catch (FileNotFoundException e)
{
    System.err.println("Exception" + e.getMessage());
}
catch (IOException e)
{
        System.err.println("Exception" + e.getMessage());
}
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
        File inputFile = new File("/bwdev/kadfeb/xls/Accredo_Kadmon_Monthly_02282014.xls");
        File outputFile = new File("output1.csv");
        convertToXls(inputFile, outputFile);
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're doing this yourself, rather than following the [Example XLS to CSV converter that Apache POI provides](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/hssf/eventusermodel/examples/XLS2CSVmra.java)?

Answer (score 5):

I assume that the [HSSFWorkbook](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html) by default skips the blank cells or missing cells. Try setting the [MissingCellPolicy](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html#getMissingCellPolicy%28%29) for the HSSFWorkbook object.

The possible values to be set for MissingCellPolicy can be found [here](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/class-use/Row.MissingCellPolicy.html)

Use row index and col index instead of Iterator.

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(inputFile));
workbook.setMissingCellPolicy(Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);

HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
for(int rowIndex = sheet.getFirstRowNum(); rowIndex < sheet.getLastRowNum(); rowIndex++)
{
       Cell cell=null;
       Row row = null;

       previousCell = -1;
       currentCell = 0;
       row = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
       for(int colIndex=row.getFirstCellNum(); colIndex < row.getLastCellNum(); colIndex++)
            {
                 cell = row.getCell(colIndex);
                 currentCell = cell.getColumnIndex();

                 /* Cell processing starts here*/
            }
    }
```

Comment: How to use MissingCellPolicy can you give example

Comment: I know it's a shocking concept, but did you consider [checking the Apache POI documentation on iterating cells?](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator) It features an example of the very same....

Comment: @Gagravarr The code that I placed there was not a complete one. I was only trying to convey the use of MissingPolicy and didn't verify the validity of the test of the code. I have updated my answer. The code that I pasted here is from sakthi's code itself.

Comment: @sakthi if the answer worked for you, do accept it please. Else share the issue faced.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class XlsxtoCSV {

    static void xlsx(File inputFile, File outputFile) {
        // For storing data into CSV files
        StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer();

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            // Get the workbook object for XLSX file
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
            Workbook workbook = null;

            String ext = FilenameUtils.getExtension(inputFile.toString());

            if (ext.equalsIgnoreCase("xlsx")) {
                workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            } else if (ext.equalsIgnoreCase("xls")) {
                workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
            }

            // Get first sheet from the workbook

            int numberOfSheets = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
            Row row;
            Cell cell;
            // Iterate through each rows from first sheet

            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSheets; i++) {
                Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
                Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

                while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                    row = rowIterator.next();
                    // For each row, iterate through each columns
                    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                        cell = cellIterator.next();

                        switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                            data.append(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + ",");

                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                            data.append(cell.getNumericCellValue() + ",");

                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                            data.append(cell.getStringCellValue() + ",");
                            break;

                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                            data.append("" + ",");
                            break;
                        default:
                            data.append(cell + ",");

                        }
                    }
                    data.append('\n'); // appending new line after each row
                }

            }
            fos.write(data.toString().getBytes());
            fos.close();

        } catch (Exception ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // testing the application

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // int i=0;
        // reading file from desktop
        File inputFile = new File(".//src//test//resources//yourExcel.xls"); //provide your path
        // writing excel data to csv
        File outputFile = new File(".//src//test//resources//yourCSV.csv");  //provide your path
        xlsx(inputFile, outputFile);
        System.out.println("Conversion of " + inputFile + " to flat file: "
                + outputFile + " is completed");
    }
}
```

Comment: This faces exactly the same problem that the OP's code does, which is that it ignores blank/missing cells, you need to use @Reji's code to properly handle them

Answer (score 0):

I replaced

```
while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
   Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
```

with

```
for (int cn = 0; cn < row.getLastCellNum(); cn++) {
   Cell cell = row.getCell(cn, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to convert xls/xlsx into csv by using apache POI.

```
public class XLSXToCSVConverter {

    public InputStream convertxlstoCSV(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {

        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);

        return  csvConverter(wb.getSheetAt(0));
    }

    private InputStream csvConverter(Sheet sheet) {
        Row row = null;
        String str = new String();
        for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getLastRowNum()+1; i++) {
            row = sheet.getRow(i);
            String rowString = new String();
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if(row.getCell(j)==null) {
                    rowString = rowString + Utility.BLANK_SPACE + Utility.COMMA;
                }
                else {
                    rowString = rowString + row.getCell(j)+ Utility.COMMA;
                }
            }
            str = str + rowString.substring(0,rowString.length()-1)+ Utility.NEXT_LINE_OPERATOR;
        }
        System.out.println(str);
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is this Utility class? I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this one. It is very similiar to previos ones, but have for loop instead of iterator, whick gives you oportunity not to skip empty (deleted) cells

```
    public InputStream fromExcelToCsv(Sheet sheet, String delimiter) throws IOException {
        // For storing data into CSV files
        StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Row row;
        // Iterate through each rows from first sheet

        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            row = rowIterator.next();

            for (int i = row.getFirstCellNum(); i < row.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
                Cell cell = row.getCell(i);
                if (cell == null) {
                    //cell is deletd => add empty
                    data.append(delimiter);
                } else {
                    switch (cell.getCellTypeEnum()) {
                        case BOOLEAN:
                            data.append(cell.getBooleanCellValue()).append(delimiter);

                            break;
                        case NUMERIC:
                            double numericCellValue = cell.getNumericCellValue();
                            //All numbers in excel is double. example: 1.0
                            //If there is no 
fractional part than delete it
                            if (numericCellValue % 1 == 0) {
                                data.append((int) numericCellValue).append(delimiter);
                            } else {
                                data.append(numericCellValue).append(delimiter);
                            }

                            break;
                        case STRING:
                            data.append(cell.getStringCellValue()).append(delimiter);
                            break;

                        case BLANK:
                            data.append(delimiter);
                            break;
                        default:
                            data.append(cell).append(delimiter);

                    }
                }
            }

            data.append('\n'); // appending new line after each row
        }

        byteArrayOutputStream.write(data.toString().getBytes());
        byteArrayOutputStream.close();

        return new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
    }
```